# php EmailSender library doesn't work

Tags: phpmailer

I developed sending email functionality using phpMailer library in an ubuntu 16.04 environment. Same code doesn't work in Windows 10 environment. Should I change the composer or .htaccess files?

```
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("lib/class.emailSender.php");


$name = isset($_GET["name"]) ? $_GET["name"] : null;
$email = isset($_GET["email"]) ? $_GET["email"] : null;
$destination = isset($_GET["destination"]) ? $_GET["destination"] : null;
$intention = isset($_GET["intention"]) ? $_GET["intention"] : null;
$route = isset($_GET["route"]) ? $_GET["route"] : null;
$accommodation = isset($_GET["accommodation"]) ? $_GET["accommodation"] : null;
$locations = isset($_GET["locations"]) ? $_GET["locations"] : array();

try {

   $emailSender = new EmailSender();

 $replace_keywords = array("%user_name%" => $name, "%email%" => $email,"%destination%" => $destination,"%intention%" => $intention,"%route%" => $route,"%accommodation%" => $accommodation,"%locations%" => $locations);
   $emailSender->sendEmailByTemplate(array($email), "Message from Smart Trip Adviser", "trip-plan.html", $replace_keywords);

      } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo ("error");

  }
```

Comment: This is unanswerable. You need to define "Does't work". Reading the troubleshooting guide would probably help too.

Comment: It is better if you can you add your code samples and update the question. Then others can get a clear understanding about your issue.